# SUM DATA SELECT - 2 person with this same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query show two person with name "Anna", "Szymkowiak" and this same "id" but this is this same person. How can I sum this? For example:id "80", "Anna", "Szymkowiak", "23", 2 -> 23 is sum of month 20 plus 3 and 2 is sum of Aneks 1 plus 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT SBA.HRSystemId AS Id, SBA.FirstName,  SBA.Surname, 
    CASE WHEN SBA.EndDate < GETDATE() 
    THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SBA.StartDate,SBA.EndDate)
    ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH,SBA.StartDate, GETDATE()) 
    END AS Miesiace_Przepracowane,
    MAX(SBC.ContractNumber) AS Aneks
    FROM SB_Applications SBA JOIN SB_Contracts SBC ON SBA.ApplicationId = SBC.ApplicationId 
    WHERE SBA.IsActiveYN = 1 AND SBA.HRSystemId != 0 AND SBC.ApplicationStatusId = 4
    GROUP BY SBA.FirstName, SBA.Surname,SBA.StartDate,SBA.EndDate,SBA.StartDate,SBA.HRSystemId,SBC.ContractNumber;
```

and I get this:

```
id |FirstName|Surname|Miesiace_Przepracowane|Aneks
80, Anna, Szymkowiak, 20, 1
80, Anna, Szymkowiak, 3, 1
91, Jack, Sparrow, 2, 1
92, Tom, Jones, 1, 1
100, Rocky, Balboa, 3, 0
```

this example doesn't work
[image]

Thanks for help colleagues this was very good training for me :) I gave you point for helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost never want to use DISTINCT when you already have GROUP BY; it's extraneous.
The most natural and quickest way is to extend your query using a derived table:

```
SELECT HRSystemId, FirstName, SurName,
       Sum(Miesiace_Przepracowane) Miesiace_Przepracowane,
       MAX(Aneks) Aneks
FROM
(
    SELECT SBA.HRSystemId AS Id, SBA.FirstName,  SBA.Surname, 
        CASE WHEN SBA.EndDate < GETDATE() 
        THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SBA.StartDate,SBA.EndDate)
        ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH,SBA.StartDate, GETDATE()) 
        END AS Miesiace_Przepracowane,
        MAX(SBC.ContractNumber) AS Aneks
        FROM SB_Applications SBA JOIN SB_Contracts SBC ON SBA.ApplicationId = SBC.ApplicationId 
        WHERE SBA.IsActiveYN = 1 AND SBA.HRSystemId != 0 AND SBC.ApplicationStatusId = 4
        GROUP BY SBA.FirstName, SBA.Surname,SBA.StartDate,SBA.EndDate,SBA.StartDate,SBA.HRSystemId,SBC.ContractNumber
) X
GROUP BY HRSystemId, FirstName, SurName;
```

Comment: Since Aneks can change, then you remove it from the outer group by and choose MAX(Anex) instead

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ID,FirstName,Surname,SUM(Miesiace_Przepracowane) as Miesiace_Przepracowane,SUM(Aneks) as Aneks from
(
SELECT DISTINCT SBA.HRSystemId AS Id, SBA.FirstName,  SBA.Surname, 
    CASE WHEN SBA.EndDate < GETDATE() 
    THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SBA.StartDate,SBA.EndDate)
    ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH,SBA.StartDate, GETDATE()) 
    END AS Miesiace_Przepracowane,
    MAX(SBC.ContractNumber) AS Aneks
    FROM SB_Applications SBA JOIN SB_Contracts SBC ON SBA.ApplicationId = SBC.ApplicationId 
    WHERE SBA.IsActiveYN = 1 AND SBA.HRSystemId != 0 AND SBC.ApplicationStatusId = 4
    GROUP BY SBA.FirstName, SBA.Surname,SBA.StartDate,SBA.EndDate,SBA.StartDate,SBA.HRSystemId,SBC.ContractNumber;
) a
Group by  ID,FirstName,Surname
```

Comment: this things I have got red - Id,FirstName,Surname, Miesiace_Przepracowane, Aneks in your SELECT, I don`t know why?